# Image is enlarging when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am displaying multiple images using a carousel. Images are displayed perfectly initially but when I scroll down and come back up, each of the images gets enlarged that they occupy the entire screen. Are there any fundamental properties that I am missing in code?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#thecarousel").owlCarousel(
    {items : 3,
    loop : true,
    margin : 1,
    dots : true,
    autoplay : true,
    autoplayTimeout : 1300,
    autoplayHoverPause : false,
    responsive : {
          0 : {
              items : 1
          },
          400 : {
              items : 2
          },
          768 : {
              items : 3
          }
      }
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" id="thecarousel">
<div class="item" style="width:280%">
  <div class="col-xs-4" style="padding:30px">
    <a>
      <img src="{% static "images/Akorn" %}" alt="" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to include the framework you have used too. The example does not work.

Comment: I am using Django for the development.

Comment: You need to include the javascript code for owlCarousel. Try to run the code snippet and see for yourself.